# Where I should place the jsp files in a spring-boot project

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Recently, I start to work with the spring-boot, and I am trying convert my old spring projects, all of them being web applications, to use this. I manage to compile, package and run the application, but when I try access them in the browser, I can't reach out my views.

First, I try put the jsp pages in the usual folder src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp, but after read this article from official documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

I try put them in the folder src/main/resources. None of this works. Anyone can tell me where I should put this files to allow them be acessible when the application is running?

My pom.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.spring.app.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have this controller to map the views:

```
@Controller
public class AcessoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
    public String signin(Model model) {
        return "acesso/signin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        return "private/admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "public/index";
    }

}
```

and this configuration classes:

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value="com.spring.app")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
@Order(value=1)
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
          // Create the 'root' Spring application context
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

          // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext jspContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          jspContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

          // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
          ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(jspContext));
          dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
          dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

**DispatcherConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Import(WebAppConfig.class)
public class DispatcherConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Why are you importing the `WebAppConfig` that could duplicate all beans you have in your application. Also a `WebApplicationInitializer` doesn't do anything in a normal spring boot application (unless you aren't using Spring Boot). You should have a application class or when you want to deploy it is a war use the `SpringBootServletInitializer` instead. Judging by all the question you asked the last 2 days I strongly suggest reading up on Spring Boot and how to use it instead of trial and error and dump your questions here.

Comment: Don't use JSP! Use a real template engine like Thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

If using Jetty or Tomcat as embedded servlet container just change your packaging from jar to war, and launch it with java -jar ...